# Unexpected access to \c$ share from windows virtualbox guest to host

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using VirtualBox 4.2.6 on Windows 7 host. I have Windows 2008 R2 guest using NAT.

My host uses 192.168.100.115 IP address and is part of the domain. Guest is using two NAT adapters (10.0.2.15 and 10.0.3.15).

What is strange is that I can access `\\192.168.100.115\c$` network share from guest **without passing any credentials!**. I can't see any credentials cached both using:

```
C:\>cmdkey /list

Currently stored credentials:

* NONE *
```

and *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager*:

[image]

can anyone tell me what's going on?

EDIT: tracert:

```
C:\>tracert -d 192.168.100.115

Tracing route to 192.168.100.115 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    53 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.2.2
  2     1 ms     2 ms     1 ms  192.168.100.115

Trace complete.
```

EDIT: robocopy command

```
C:\>robocopy . \\192.168.100.115\c$\_ test.txt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Jan 31 13:22:57 2013

   Source : C:\
     Dest : \\192.168.100.115\c$\_\

    Files : test.txt

  Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    C:\
100%        New File                   0        test.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Thu Jan 31 13:22:57 2013
```

EDIT: `net session /list`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> net session /list

Nazwa użytkownika       Administrator
Komputer                192.168.100.115
Logowanie jako gość     Nie
Typ klienta
Czas bezczynności       00:00:58

Polecenie zostało wykonane pomyślnie.
```

Comment: what user are you logged in as on the VM? is there a local account on the host with the same username and password? there would be no stored credentials in that case. Check your local Administrator group membership (you need admin to hit $ shares).

Comment: That may be it. The guest is domain controller and I'm logged as domain administrator. But this virtual domain has not trust relation with the domain my host is member of... Does that mean that **any** administrator from any domain can access my `\c$`?

Comment: on the guest, connect to the host, and on the host, run this in powershell (as admin) to determine the user account being used: 'net session /list'

Comment: I've edited the question - it looks like it is local host's administrator...

Comment: so are both accounts named administrator and do they share a password?

Comment: actually ... yes. But on Linux, when you ssh from one host to another you're always being asked for password even if they match.

Comment: I've changed the virtual domain (`MS`) admin password and when I wanted to access `\c$` I was asked for password of `MS\Administrator` - I've entered **the host's local admin password** and the authentication was successful! Isn't it weird? Was it designed to work like that? Please add an answer so I can give you +25 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will automatically try any credentials tied to an interactive users account when authenticating to a remote PC over SMB, and will only ask for credentials if those it knows do not work.

in this case, the administrator user accounts exist locally, so when a user has an account on two machines that share a username and password, the user will not be prompted to authenticate.